# Can't connect to VM

Tags: google-cloud-platform

Can't connect to VM (Debian 11) over SSH. Website on server working fine.
Connection failed
You cannot connect to the VM instance because of an unexpected error. Wait a few moments and then try again.

Troubleshooting your connection
1 of 3 tests complete

VM Status - OK
Network status - endlessly pending
User Permission - endlessly pending

Connect over SSH through google remote console.

Comment: I would probably start with checking VPC firewalls (where the VM under discussion is deployed) and the VM configuration. Then, I would check user account IAM permissions. Then, VPC routes (just in case).